# Will I have time to continue reading some papers in physics after joining hedge funds?

Tags: finance

I'm a phd student in physics, and trying to find a job in hedge funds (which better value and respect scientific logic and methods very much, rather than focus on the social network. Although I'm good at social). I still like physics so much and don't want to forget all those precious knowledge I learned (with very hard work, they're difficult. PS I'm in string theory). The reason I decide not to continue the academic life is simply because I'm not doing so good. After four years, I clearly know I'm just ordinary smart and it would be very hard to get a faculty position in string theory. It's time to leave.

So, here comes the question, could I still have time to read some papers in physics as a role of quant (not in working hours of course)? The first two years would be hard of course, since as starters. How about the following years? I'm pretty sure that there must be quants from non-financial backgrounds who still love their original major, physics, chemistry,etc.

How do you guys deal with your old love (and maybe forever love) and the financial job? Thank you for any sharing.

Comment: You always have weekend.

Comment: well sure... let's not talk about those clearly available time. If look at the weekday nights, would the work often end quite late, or already exhaust yourself ? Quants at Goldman Sachs or JP morgan have very long working time...

Comment: In my experience, you'll barely be able to do anything after work as a quant. They pay you lots of money and they expect you to work hard (I mean very hard).

Comment: Your word is just what I imagined...It's really sad to walk away and forget the discipline you studied and researched for a long time. Especially when you think that discipline is so important and meaningful.

Comment: I work in finance instead of academia with a PhD in math. I used to think I didn't have time, but I did have a good bit of time to do math before my daughter was born. Now there's no time.

Comment: And yes, agree with Student in that they expect you to work hard. I work from 6 am to 5:30 pm (and I'm among the earliest to leave), am on call at night and work weekends and holidays if necessary. It used to wear me out but luckily I've adapted. It's not so bad. I just presented my math research at a conference this weekend in fact.

Comment: So impressive that with a 6am to 5:30pm schedule you could still do your research...I don't think I'm as energetic and smart as you :) Anyway, thanks for this sharing.